# How can we fetch blog posts and pages from Shopify Headless in Gatsby with gatsby-source-shopify plugin?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, shopify-api

I am planning to migrate my site from Shopify to Shopify Headless + Gatsby but I am having a problem with the plugin, gatsby-source-shopify. It can create nodes for products and product related data but not blog posts. Is there any way to get blog posts or do I have to create them manually in Gatsby.

Here is my configuration for gatsby-source-shopify plugin.

```
      resolve: `gatsby-source-shopify`,
      options: {
        password: process.env.GATSBY_SHOPIFY_PASSWORD,
        storeUrl: process.env.GATSBY_SHOPIFY_STORE_URL,
        shopifyConnections: ["collections"],
      },
    },
```

It gives products and product related nodes in GraphQL.
[Available Nodes in GraphQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSgi0.png)

I try googling but all of the tutorials and gatsby-source-shopify documentation focus on retrieving product data.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I'm thinking about using Shopify with Gatsby as well, and have been wondering about this too. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for late and I found a solution. In my case, I create a simple source plugin to fetch data and inserting them into gatsby graphql data layer. Here is the reference - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/creating-a-source-plugin/.

To fetch Blog Posts and Pages, you can use Shopify storefront API. You can also play with Storefront API with GraphQL app ( https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/login )

Comment: If you're very lazy, you could fork the gatsby-source-shopify plugin **v6** and use that alongside the main v7 one, as articles/blogs were only removed from v7

Answer (score 0):

You first have to make sure your env file has all the right credentials to make a connection to your custom app that you have created in Shopify is correct.

my env file:

[image of env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpfN2.png)

Now according to Gatsby documentation, we have to make a new source and let’s call it a “storefront”. Your Gatsby-config.js file should look like this.

[image of gatsby-config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r3Yx.png)

Run “Gatsby clean” and then Gatsby develop command in the terminal for your Gatsby. If everything goes right. You should be able to open http://localhost:8000/___graphql or whatever port you are running on (you can find that information in the terminal)

[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDEIT.png)

Open http://localhost:8000/___graphql and you should be able to see the storefront in Explorer.

[localhost graphql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBuNq.png)

Create a query and fetch it

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541